# Is it possible to resize images within your Android app in real time?

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

I am going to have this activity that will have these "bubbles", which I will add to my app as a drawable resource. Depending on the value associated with each bubble, I want to increase or decrease in size so they look bigger or smaller compared to others. I've tried the following, which didn't work:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams transportParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(t, t);
mTransportationBubble.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This code actually does resize the images, but it moves them all to the top left corner of my screen and stacks them on top of each other. Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: `... as a mipmap resource`. The `mipmap` folders should be used **uniquely** for the app icon.

Answer (score 0):

> I am going to have this activity that will have these "bubbles", which I will add to my app as a mipmap resource.

Put your images into **hdpi** folder and try again. The mipmap folder is reserved for launcher icons.

check this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information about resource folders

Comment: When I do this and try again, the bubbles do resize, but they all move to the top right of the screen and stack on top of each other, no matter where I put them in the layout file. What should I do?